# How i can get different logger for each call of function?

Tags: python, logging

I need a different logger for each call of same function.

```
loggerA = logging.getLogger('whatever1')
myfunction('A')
loggerB = logging.getLogger('whatever2')
myfunction('B')
# The loggers must not cross
```

How i can organize logging in myfunction for that? Is it possible?

Comment: This seems like an anti-pattern in logging; can you explain what you are actually trying to achieve / why you need this?

Comment: I need to use a myfunction in multiplie threads. So i wanna get a different file of log for each call of function.

Comment: @kalombo If you want to see each thread's log statements why not include thread's name in the logging statement?

Comment: Or, if you want actual separate loggers (e.g., to go to separate files), use the thread ID or name as the logging key.

Comment: @abarnert: Separate files => separate handlers, not separate loggers. The OP's requirement could be met using filters on the handlers, which only allow messages from a specific thread to pass through.

Comment: @VinaySajip: Yes, but in this case, creating a single logger with N handlers, each of which filters out N-1 cases, doesn't seem significantly simpler than using N loggers, and the latter seems to be what the OP already knows.

Comment: @abarnert: Agreed, but creating N loggers will not get their events into N different log files; you'd need N different handlers for that. I wouldn't adopt this approach myself - the straightforward thing would be to get the thread name into the messages written into a single log file, then use e.g. `grep` to filter the messages :-)

Comment: @VinaySajip: I agree, using a single log file and trivially smarter processing tools is almost always better. In fact, when I've been forced to split logs into multiple files, e.g., because the code is transparently distributed across separate computers, the first thing my processing code has to do is merge them together…

Answer (score 0):

You could always:

```
def myfunction(some_arg):
    logger = logging.getLogger("myfunction." + str(some_arg))
    # whatever else
```

But, I agree with Vinay - this is an antipattern!